# Run multiple stages of Jenkins declarative pipe line in same docker slave

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

**Objective**

Objective here to migrate a scripted jenkins pipe line to declarative .Scripted pipe line is running on docker slave managed by kubernetes and the working syntax is as below

```
 slave = 'dtr@tes.com/namespace/image:1.0'

dockerNode(image:slave)
{

   stage('1'){echo "1"}

   stage('2'){echo "2"} 

}
```

The scripted pipe line is working perfect .

**Concerns**

Trying to use dockerNode to declrative pipeline but in declarative the dockerNode syntax is allowed only after stepes inside a stage

eg:

```
pipeline{
  agent any 
  stages{
    stage('1and2'}{
      dockerNode(image:slave){

        echo "1"
        echo "2" 
    }
  }
 }
}
```

This is making concern to club bulky steps in to one stage than in to multiple one .So we would like your help to understand how can we better align and have multiple stages that is running in same container always .The container images is managed by kubernetes (kube pod with docker images)

Answer (score 0):

To use one container for all steps you need to specify it in agent section

```
pipeline{
  agent {
    label 'docker-agent-label'
  }
}
```

To use like so you need to configure pod template in 'Manage jenkins' -> 'Manage nodes and
Clouds' -> 'Configure clouds' -> 'Add new cloud' or use existing one.
It must be kubernetes if your jenkins host integrated with k8s.

UPDATE:

[image: example of configuring docker agent template]

Comment: thank you .Can you give me an indication on what is label ,label indicating the cloud entry or the image name mentioned above ? If its a kube cloud entry where will i mention the specified image i wish to use ?

Comment: Take a look at the picture. Labels let you call any agent without to remember it's name. If you don't know how to setup it, try to call docker image directly in pipeline. Read this article about using docker within pipeline [link](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/docker/)

Comment: We dont use any cloud ,what we used in scripted with dockerNode as under Jenkins > Configure system >Docker Slaves >Docker provisioner >Type Compose Container with below details Remoting Image ,Docker API to use ,Select docker using swarm ,docker host URI .So what can i translate to declarative here (

Comment: Jenkins' developers call it like clouds (doesn't matter if you are using local docker env or a real cloud, update your jenkins to latest LTS version and you will see it). In any case you need to have docker installed and jenkins configured to run agents/slaves in docker.

Comment: Again I guess we are going in two different aspects ,if you see for dockerNode with Docker provisioner usage there absolutely no entry needed under manage Jenkins >cloud and that section will be empty .Also I could use dockerNode under stage for declarative like stages >stages('')>steps >dockerNode(image:slave_images) and will work perfectly but only for a specific stage .This is a context and question specific to dockerNode which is marked as an experimental in Jenkins page.Also in this case no docker commands at the master node rather it fetch the orchestrator in our case kubernetes and run

Comment: dockerNode for scripted reference ,and for declarative its looks like only under a step but what i am looking to use this for whole pipe line  https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/docker-plugin/#dockernode-docker-node-%EF%B8%8F-experimental